# 301 redirect problem in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .htaccess

I am developed web site with .NET,now i want to implement 301 redirect(non www to www).I have used theis code

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.com [NC]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxx.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But i didn't redirect with www.
I have used following settings in File Zilla.

My site port NO:10021

Protocal:FTP

Encryption:Require explicity FTP over TLS

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's an .htaccess file which is for Apache servers. See [this blog post for URL writing with .Net](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your replay,But same code is working for another .NET application but that application doesn't have port number

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing URL Routing.. I wrote this [article](http://chadcarter30101.blogspot.com/2011/07/url-routing-in-aspnet-40-simple-example.html) to do it in .Net 4.0...
If you are wanting to do a 301 Permanent Change... At the end of this [article](http://chadcarter30101.blogspot.com/2011/08/aspnet-40-head-tag-and-elements-new.html) you will see how to do it in .Net 4.0.  Otherwise you have to put a page out there and do a Response.Redirect (which does not update Search Engines - The new 4.0 method does).